# How to calculate variance of zero-inflated beta distribution?

Tags: probability, variance

The pdf of the zero-inflated beta distribution is as follows:

\begin{equation}
  f(y; \mu, \sigma, \nu) =
    \begin{cases}
      \nu & \text{if $y=0$}\\
      (1-\nu)f(y;\mu, \sigma) & \text{if $y \in (0,1)$}
    \end{cases} 
    \label{eqn:5}
\end{equation}

where $f(y;\mu, \sigma)$ is $\frac{\Gamma(\sigma)}{\Gamma(\mu\sigma)\Gamma((1-\mu)\sigma))}*y^{\mu\sigma-1}*(1-y)^{(1-\mu)\sigma-1}$

The variance is [claimed to be](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/gamlss.dist/html/BEZI.html):

$$(1-\nu)*\frac{\mu*(1-\mu)}{\sigma+1} + \nu*(1-\nu)*\mu^2$$

How is that variance derived?

Comment: Please define what is $f(y;\mu, \sigma) $...

Comment: Added pdf of $f(y; \mu, \sigma)$

Comment: In this [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.0700.pdf), they give their formulas (3) without explanation.

Comment: Interesting things in this [MSc Thesis](https://ourspace.uregina.ca/bitstream/handle/10294/9253/Ji_Bowen_MSC_STATS_Spring2020.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Comment: Don't forget to say the few words "thank you" for the remarkable solution by heropup.

Comment: @JeanMarie I thought we [weren't supposed to leave "thank you" comments](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/what-is-the-etiquette-about-leaving-short-thank-you-comments)

Comment: This is something I am against: writing "thank you" takes so few bits compared to the smallest image, and especially in this COVID times where it brings some warmth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X \sim \operatorname{Beta}(\mu, \sigma)$ with the parametrization you have specified, and $B \sim \operatorname{Bernoulli}(1-\nu)$ with $\Pr[B = 1] = 1-\nu$, where $B$ and $X$ are independent, then $Y = BX$ is zero-inflated beta with the density you have also specified.  Then by the law of total variance,
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[Y] &= \operatorname{E}[\operatorname{Var}[BX \mid B]] + \operatorname{Var}[\operatorname{E}[BX \mid B]] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[B^2 \operatorname{Var}[X]] + \operatorname{Var}[B\operatorname{E}[X]] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[X]\operatorname{E}[B^2] + \operatorname{E}[X]^2\operatorname{Var}[B].
\end{align}$$
Since $\operatorname{E}[B^2] = \operatorname{E}[B] = 1-\nu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[B] = \nu (1-\nu)$, the rest is straightforward; all that is needed is to compute the mean and variance of $X$ for the choice of parametrization you used.

Comment: [+1] Wow : The keypoint is to write it as a product BX (I should have guessed it), whereas I was stumped by the consideration of a mixture between a dirac and a beta distribution...

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.